# Should I enable backports repositories on Ubuntu Server (LAMP)?

Tags: server, lamp, webserver, backport

Is there any disadvantages/advantages on enabling backports repositories on my new Ubuntu Server (LAMP)? What I should choose?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with your current setup and want stability then backports are not for you but if you want cutting edge for some reason, then enable them, I wouldn't on a server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll stay than with default server repositories.